# Hbase 0.92.1 Secondary Index Example

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I am working on million Rows and columns in hbase 0.92.1. Now, I want to know how to create secondary index using Co-processor. Give some examples program for this. 
Kindly give the program which supports hbase 0.92.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, prior to 0.20, in Hbase API, you'd have HTableDescriptor which is writable still, so you can call HtabelDescriptor.addIndex() to create indices against the columns. 
Example can be found [here](http://blog.rajeevsharma.in/2009/06/secondary-indexes-in-hbase.html).

Then indexing starts moving to IHbase see the Jira story [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2037).

To answer your question, in 0.92.1, I don't think there is anything out of box **yet**, you will have to write the coprocessor yourself, But There is a jira story for [coprocessor secondary index](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3340) you might want to watch the progress:)

meanwhile you can try idxColumnDescriptor [here](https://github.com/ykulbak/ihbase/wiki/Getting-Started), also looking at the test [TestIdxColumnDescriptor.java](https://github.com/ykulbak/ihbase/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/idx/TestIdxColumnDescriptor.java) might help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no single great way to do secondary indexing with HBase.  The way you will approach the problem will be dictated by your data and your use case.  Some good discussion of secondary indexing is located [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/secondary.indexes.html)